# Open source policy editor tool for XACML 3.0 policy creation

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, xacml2

I am using XACML 3.0 for authorization in my project is their any open source policy editor tool so that I can create policies on the fly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good and easy-to-use XACML GUI editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657821/good-and-easy-to-use-xacml-gui-editor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several open source policies editors.  As i know,

1. [UMU XACML editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/umu-xacmleditor/)
2. [WSO2 Identity Server](http://xacmlinfo.org/tag/policy-editor/)
3. OpenAM Server

Also Non open sources, but you can download freely such as

1. [ALFA Plugin](https://www.axiomatics.com/axiomatics-alfa-plugin-for-eclipse.html) by [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com) (non-commercial use)
2. [Free GUI based XACML Editor](https://securitypolicytool.com/) (XACML2.0 to XACML3.0 conversion)

If you want to integrate policy creation in to your project. I guess, best approach is to use Balana utils library. It is a library that can be used to create XACML 3.0 policies and XACML 3.0 request using an simple object model. You find the source code of Balana util from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-utils/). Basically WSO2 Identity Server policy editors are used this library to build the policies.

Comment: Balana source which you specified its not buildable completely its giving maven build error SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

Comment: We did not have experienced such issue. I have just tried with clean M2 repo..  It builds without any issue. Maven version is "Apache Maven 3.0.4 "  and JDK is 1.6.29.  Could you please verify this again.

Comment: I am using Apache Maven version 3.1.0 and Java version 1.7.0_25

Comment: ok i will try with that vresion , is there any whitepaper on wso2.utils library

Comment: Sorry.. nop.. these is no about Balana utils library

Comment: I tried with Maven ver 3.0.5 still POM file is dependent on Parent pom file  so its not allowing me to download complete dependencies of maven, can you please check and share working one with  me...

Comment: yes..but also, Please try to get svn up from http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/  and then try to build