# Good and easy-to-use XACML GUI editor?

Tags: user-interface, access-control, xacml

I have need to do the authorization for my web service. And I want to design some XACML policies to do the job. But they are a little complicated for me (forgive me that I'm a newbee to security policy). I feel I have the need to have a GUI editor to help me do the design. But I haven't found a good GUI editor except UMU-XACML-Editor, which is no longer actively developed currently.

In my humble opinion, a XACML PDP server maybe too heavy for me. I just want to have a GUI policy editor, maybe a desktop software or a web-based UI. Is there a tool like this?

Comment: A bit too late, but still: asking for recommendations is **off topic**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools, editors, and PDPs available:

- Axiomatics Policy Server ([YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZ73VnNaazs)) contains both a web-based ui and a desktop client.
- the [ALFA plugin for Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)#The_ALFA_plugin_for_Eclipse)
- AT&T XACML